# How to use Spring Session + Spring security xml configuration and multiply security filter

Tags: spring-security, spring-session, spring-data-redis

### Background

Hey all,
We have `Spring` project which uses `Spring security`. We have defined the security filters by defining

```
 <b:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
```

whith `filter-chain-map`

and in the `web.xml` we do

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and it all works well :). Now when hooking up `Spring session` with `redis` according to the `doc`  the next following lines

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
```

create a `filter` named `springSessionRepositoryFilter`. So basically what we did is in every custom `filter-chain` we add that filter to be the *very first filter* . i.e:

```
<b:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"   class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
     <filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">

           <filter-chain pattern="/api/someapieformobilelogin" filters="none" />  <!-- no filter on login -->
        <filter-chain pattern="/api/**"
            filters="springSessionRepositoryFilter, securityContextFilter,and some other spring security filter />

        <filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="springSessionRepositoryFilter, securityContextFilter,and some other spring security filter />
```

**The results**: the app seems to work good and also `monitoring` via `redis-cli` shows the `spring` is communicating with `redis`.

### The question

Does the use of `springSessionRepositoryFilter` inside the `filter-chain` is ok? or we abused the filtering system?

Thanks,

Oak

### Edit

It seems that above will not work for the case one wants to `Authenticate` the user from code i.e

```
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(authenticationToken);
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext();
securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
```

will failed. Maybe because its not enough to run it via `filter-chain` of `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy`.

What do you think on run it as `filter` in `web.xml`?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The above will force running `springSessionRepositoryFilter` before `springSecurityFilterChain` but in this example `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` is being called twice. any other ways to make `springSessionRepositoryFilter` run as a filter before out `springSecurityFilterChain` filter?

Comment: I know this is an old question. bu did you find a solution for this problem? I currently face the same issue

Comment: This indeed old question, I think i can look the answer somehwere. Do you still need it?

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply. We removed spring-session from our project temporaly because we couldn't fix this issue. If it takes too much time you dont have to search for the answer

Comment: Hey there, I added my answer to this question. Hope it can help you to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

According to my testing,  `springSessionRepositoryFilter` must run first. This is due the fact that `springSessionRepositoryFilter` replaces the `HttpSession` implementation.  Here is my solution using `xml` files.

### redis-cache.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher" />

<!-- end of seesion managment configuration -->


<bean id="redisConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="port" value="${app.redis.port}" />
    <property name="hostName" value="${app.redis.hostname}" />
    <property name="password" value="${app.redis.password}" />
    <property name="usePool" value="true" />
</bean>
```

> We use the combination of  and RedisHttpSessionConfiguration because Spring Session does not yet provide XML Namespace support (see gh-104). This creates a Spring Bean with the name of springSessionRepositoryFilter that implements Filter. The filter is what is in charge of replacing the HttpSession implementation to be backed by Spring Session. In this instance Spring Session is backed by Redis.
>   [source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-xml.html#httpsession-xml-spring-configuration)

Now, as we have the `session filter` named `springSessionRepositoryFilter` it must run as the first filter because it replaces the `HttpSession` implementation.

In order to do so, we declare it as the first filter in `web.xml`. For more info about filters and filter's order checkout the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000023)

### web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/redis-cache.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Note that the first to run is `springSessionRepositoryFilter`. But actully `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` class is running and it looks for the filter by the bean's name. So it search for the bean created by our early configurations.
[reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-xml.html#xml-servlet-container-initialization)

The extra line about the `redis-cache.xml` are important as well. Otherwise our `spring` `application context` cannot know about our redis configuration

[reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-create)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I we have a similar setup now but we still have problems for some requests. Do you think two DelegatingFilterProxys could be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.html):

> The SessionRepositoryFilter must be placed before any Filter that access the HttpSession or that might commit the response to ensure the session is overridden and persisted properly.

So long as you add `springSessionRepositoryFilter` before anything that can commit the response or access the `HttpSession`, you are fine. In the case of Spring Security the main thing you will want to ensure is that `springSessionRepositoryFilter` is before the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`. This can be done by including `springSessionRepositoryFilter` within the container or within Spring Security's `FilterChainProxy` (i.e. `<filter-chain>`).

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. The solution above raised some issue. for example trying to do `SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();  securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);` from code seems not to get run. My thoughts that even this filter is set to be the first via `<filter-chain>` its still not enough and should run before it. what do you think?